Distribution of this integral of Fourier multiplier
In Barashkov and Gubinelli (2019) section 2, the authors make the claim that the distribution of $$Y_t = \int_0^t \langle D \rangle^{-1}\sigma_s(D)dX_s$$ is given by the pushforward $(\rho_t(D))_*\vartheta$ of $\vartheta$ through $\rho_t(D)$, but this is not apparent to me. Any nudges in the correct direction will be appreciated.
The setup here is as follows: $\vartheta$ is the centred Gaussian measure with covariance $(1-\Delta)^{-1}$, with $\Delta$ the Laplacian on $\Lambda:=(\mathbb{R}/(2\pi L\mathbb{Z}))^d$. $X_t$ here is the canonical process on $\Omega :=C(\mathbb{R}_+;H^{-\alpha})$. By taking the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, and the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ which makes $X$ a cyndrical Brownian motion, we know there exists a collection of $2$-dimensional Brownian motions $(B^n_t)_{n\in(L^{-1}\mathbb{Z})^d}$, such that $X_t=|\Lambda|^{-1/2}\sum_{n\in(L^{-1}\mathbb{Z})^d}e^{i\langle n, \cdot\rangle}B_t^n$. With $\rho\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}_+,\mathbb{R}_+)$ such that $\rho(0)=1$, and $\rho_t(x):=\rho(x/t)$, one sets $\sigma_t(x):=(2\dot{\rho}_t(x)\rho_t(x))^{1/2}$. Finally $g(D)$ is used for the Fourier multiplier associated with symbol g, and $\langle n\rangle := (1 + n^2)^{1/2}$.
